# Autodesk get the urn data from children

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

[image: I have added the screenshot of viewerDcoument data which I am getting]

Hello,

In the attached image, I want to know how can I get the urn data from children
"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Ymltb21hdGljYXBwL0pDSSUyMFB1bmUlMjA1dGglMjBGbG9vciUyMFYzLm53Yw/output/0/properties.db".
the file type is properties.db

Answer (score 0):

That **SQLite** database file contains all the properties that got extracted from the original model file. You can simply download it using this **Model Derivative API** endpoint: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/ 
More info on working with that file: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-viewer-data-serverlessly-thumbnails-screesnshots-and-serverless-upload

And the following article shows the various ways you can access the properties that got extracted from the original model file:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer